# What happens when you iterate Cohen reals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

There are a few classical theorems in set theory:

1. The finite support iteration of ccc forcing is ccc.
2. The countable support iteration of proper forcing is proper.
3. The finite support iteration of length $\omega$, Cohen forcing is a Cohen forcing.

But what happens when you iterate Cohen forcing with a *countable support* iteration of length $\omega$?

What do we already know:

1. This is a proper forcing. Because Cohen forcing is proper.
2. This is not a ccc forcing, because we iterate with full support.

> What can you say about the full/countable support iteration of length $\omega$ of Cohen forcings?
>
> Specifically, does it add non-Cohen reals? Does it collapse any cardinals?

Comment: Related: [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193936/products-of-cohen-forcings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193936/products-of-cohen-forcings)

Comment: Well, not *really* related. Just vaguely related, I'd say. :)

Comment: I think it's consistent that it collapses cardinals: unless I'm mistaken, I think it should collapse $\mathfrak{c}^V$ to $\mathfrak{d}^V$. (The reason: if $\mathcal D$ is a dominating family of functions in the ground model, and if $g: \omega \times \omega \rightarrow 2$ is the generic object added by your forcing, then a density argument shows that $\{ g \circ f \,:\, f \in \mathcal D \}$ contains $(2^\omega)^V$.)

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant the function $n \mapsto g(n,f(n))$, not $g \circ f$ (which isn't well-defined).

Comment: Regarding Mohammad's link, it's important to specify what exactly you are iterating when you have infinite supports. If you take a nice enough full name at each stage then what you wrote is true and the whole iteration is proper. But if you take the check name at each stage, you just get back the product, which will collapse $\omega_1$.

Comment: @Miha: I expected that this is clear enough that we iterate in the proper sense of iteration. Also, I figured that people would give me some leeway that I know that iterating with ground model posets is the same as a product. I guess I was wrong... :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know if this is useful for you, but you can show that the forcing does not add random reals, and even more. see [No random reals in countable support iterations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02762088).